# Strong Induction Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have a quick question about strong induction. If I’m proving that P(k+1) is true for a certain statement, can I use only P(k) within my proof to show that P(k+1) holds? Or would that be considered weak induction?

Comment: If you use only the truth of $P(k)$ to prove $P(k+1)$ then it's just ordinary (weak) induction. If you have been assigned a problem and told to use strong induction it may be necessary in that case. Check your argument.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you for your response! so if i was assigned a problem and told to use strong induction, would be okay to use only the truth of p(k) to prove p(k+1)?

Comment: If your goal is to do what the teacher asks, then you should use strong induction. If your goal is to prove the assertion in the simplest way and weak induction works, that's a little better. If you're told to use strong induction in _may be_ that there is no easy correct proof without it.

Comment: Weak induction is a subset of strong induction. What is strong about strong induction is that you *can* assume that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \le k$ in the induction step. But in particular, that implies that $P(k)$ is true, so if you can show $P(k+1)$ just from $P(k)$, that is sufficient. You have still shown that $(\forall n \le k, P(n)) \implies P(k+1)$, which is the condition for strong induction. You do not have to involve $P(n)$ for $n < k$ in your proof somehow when it isn't necessary.